# ASP.NET MVC routing to action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect

I'm  having trouble doing what I want to achieve when doing routing in ASP.NET MVC. 
What I want to do is the following:

1. When typing `http://localhost/MyWebsite/`, I want to redirect to `http://localhost/MyWebsite/Login/` (The redirection to the action `Index` is implied here)
2. When typing `http://localhost/MyWebsite/MyAction`, I want to redirect to `http://localhost/MyWebsite/Login/MyAction`

Point 1 was achieved using the following lines in the file RouteConfig.cs:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

But I cannot accomplish point 2. Note that the user does not come from another action in a controller, but actually types the address in his browser.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since `/MyWebsite/Login` and `/MyWebsite/MyAction` both have two segments in the URL, they're both matching your defined Route.

You can use a Route Constraint to only match `/MyWebsite/Login` to your first point, followed by a modified second route mapping:

```
     routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Default",
         url: "MyWebsite/Login/",
         defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });


     routes.MapRoute(
             name: "Actions",
             url: "MyWebsite/{action}/",
             defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```